# Set ringtone using RingtoneManager

Tags: android

> ** I am unable to find my mistake  **

```
String filepath = getResources() + "raw/" + mp_name;
        Uri defaultRintoneUri = RingtoneManager.getActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
                getApplicationContext(), RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
        final File ringtoneFile = new File(filepath);
        final Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media
                .getContentUriForPath(ringtoneFile.getAbsolutePath());

        final ContentValues content = new ContentValues();
        content.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA,
                ringtoneFile.getAbsolutePath());
        content.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/*");


content.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
                    Uri newUri = getContentResolver().insert(uri, content);
                    RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
                            getApplicationContext(),
                            RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, newUri);
```

> *Please help me figure out how can I perfectly set Ringtone  *

Answer (score 1):

public void pickRingtone(View view) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method.   stub

```
    Intent intent = new.       Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
    intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TYPE,
            RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
    intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TITLE, "Select Ringtone");

// for existing ringtone
    Uri urie =     RingtoneManager.getActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
            getApplicationContext(), RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
    intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_EXISTING_URI, urie);

startActivityForResult(intent, 5);
```

}

Comment: Thanks Manish, but I have audio file in may application I want to set that audio file as ringtone So I dose'n need to create a ring tone, I am gettint my newuri = null